# Filter a column and put value in next column till the end

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I need to Filter Column I with text that contains "AED" and put "DCL" as Value in Column P

Below Just paste in all rows without considering the filter

Kindly help to fix

```
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="="
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="=*AED*" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
Range("P6").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DCL"
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

In your case (not tested):

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Paste
```

and remove

> ActiveSheet.Paste